# I need help passing parameters from Ajax to a C# method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

Alright... So basically I'm creating a "global search" for a table that contains over 4000 records... I got most of it working... I placed stop points in the ajax call and it is giving the parameters that were selected from the drop down list.

Problem: In the action method the parameters are "Null" even though when I checked to see the JS it has the variables with values there...

I am trying to generate a datatable based on the parameters that are selected...

What I need is help passing the results from the AJAX call to the C# method that is actually doing the searching of table...

Here is the code...

```
function materialType() {
    $('#search_results').html("Loading...");
    var material_type = $('#material_type_name').find(':selected').text();
    var search_query = $('#query').val();
    var sub_type = "";
    //var params = JSON.stringify({ 'search_query': search_query, 'type_name': material_type, 'sub_type_name': sub_type })
    $.ajax({
        url: "/AdvancedMaterialSearch/MultipleParams",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ search_query: search_query, type_name: material_type, sub_type_name: sub_type }),
        dataType: 'json',
        //dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#search_results').html(data);
            $('#results').DataTable();
        }
    });
```

​
    }

```
public ActionResult MultipleParams(string search_query,string type_name,string sub_type_name)
    {
        try
        {
            var str_query = "";
            var material_type_id = 0;
            var str_sub_type = "";

            if (search_query != null)
            {
                str_query = search_query;
            }

            if (type_name != null)
            {
                material_type_id = db.t_material_types.FirstOrDefault(x => x.material_type == type_name).material_type_id;
            }
            if(sub_type_name != null)
            {
                str_sub_type = sub_type_name;
            }

            //check if str_query is entered but NO material_type was selected
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str_query) && material_type_id == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.SearchResults = db.t_material_master.Where(s =>s.color_code.Contains(str_query) || s.color_name.Contains(str_query) || s.description.Contains(str_query) || s.sap_number.Contains(str_query) || s.width.Contains(str_query) || s.weight.Contains(str_query) || s.size.Contains(str_query) || s.uom.material_uom_name.Contains(str_query) || s.vendor.vendor_name.Contains(str_query)).ToList();
                if (ViewBag.SearchResults.Count == 0)
                {
                    return PartialView("/Views/AdvancedMaterialSearch/SearchResultPartials/_NoResultsFound.cshtml");
                }
            }

            //check if str_query is NOT entered but a material_type WAS selected
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str_query) && material_type_id != 0)
            {
                ViewBag.SearchResults = db.t_material_master.Where(s => s.material_type_id == material_type_id).ToList();
                if (ViewBag.SearchResults.Count == 0)
                {
                    return PartialView("/Views/AdvancedMaterialSearch/SearchResultPartials/_NoResultsFound.cshtml");
                }
            }

            //check if both str_query IS entered and a material_type WAS selected
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str_query) && material_type_id != 0)
            {
                ViewBag.SearchResults = db.t_material_master.Where(s => s.material_type_id == material_type_id && s.color_code.Contains(str_query) || s.color_name.Contains(str_query) || s.description.Contains(str_query) || s.sap_number.Contains(str_query) || s.width.Contains(str_query) || s.weight.Contains(str_query) || s.size.Contains(str_query) || s.uom.material_uom_name.Contains(str_query) || s.vendor.vendor_name.Contains(str_query)).ToList();
                if (ViewBag.SearchResults.Count == 0)
                {
                    return PartialView("/Views/AdvancedMaterialSearch/SearchResultPartials/_NoResultsFound.cshtml");
                }
            }
            return PartialView("/Views/AdvancedMaterialSearch/SearchResultPartials/_SearchFieldOnly.cshtml");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Print(e.Message);
            return PartialView("/Views/AdvancedMaterialSearch/SearchResultPartials/_NoResultsFound.cshtml");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pass a javascript object to the data of the ajax method, you shouldn't need to stringify it.  MVC 4+ does that under the hood.  Just make sure your javascript objects property names match the variable names on your MultipleParams function. If not make a new javascript object and copy from the previous javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `JSON.stringify`, just change `data` of ajax call as shown:-

```
data: { search_query: search_query, type_name: material_type, sub_type_name: sub_type },
```

and since you are returning `PartialView`(HTML) from controller action, so change `dataType` as shown:-

```
dataType: 'html',// it should be html not json
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
data: { search_query: search_query, type_name: material_type, sub_type_name: sub_type }
```

Without the JSON.stringify, it should work depending on which version of MVC you are using.